# lua wireshark plugin dissector buffer length

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

How can I get the length of buffer data in dissector function. The type is `userdata` in lua, it points to raw memory. I have tried to convert it to metatable, but still cannot get the length of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
function dissector(buffer,pinfo,tree)
    print(buffer:len())
end
```